# Passing 'float' to incompatible type of 'float*'

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, vector

I am trying to create a vector using the method GLKVector3MakeWithArray.

I am getting the following error and I am a bit puzzled as to why, "Passing 'float' to incompatible type of 'float*'"

Here is my code:

```
    [self.offsetArray addObject:[jsnmphset valueForKey:@"offset"]];

    // Create a Vector3f from the array offset stored in the nsdictionary
    GLKVector3 offset = GLKVector3MakeWithArray([[self.offsetArray objectAtIndex:0] floatValue]);
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you think the error might mean? What have you tried to do to correct the problem? What information did you glean thus far in your search for a solution? In short, [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: I've created a work around by doing the following:         GLKVector3 offset = GLKVector3Make(
                                           [[self.offsetArray objectAtIndex:0] floatValue],
                                           [[self.offsetArray objectAtIndex:1] floatValue],
                                           [[self.offsetArray objectAtIndex:2] floatValue]
                                           );

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GLKVector3MakeWithArray is defined like this:

```
GLKVector3 GLKVector3MakeWithArray( float values[3] );
```

It take an array of three float values. You are calling it as if it were defined like this:

```
GLKVector3 GLKVector3MakeWithArray( float value );
```

You are passing in a single float value.

You will need to do something like this:

```
float values[3];

values[0] = [[self.offsetArray objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];
values[1] = [[self.offsetArray objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];
values[2] = [[self.offsetArray objectAtIndex:2] floatValue];

GLKVector3 offset = GLKVector3MakeWithArray( values );
```

Now, whether '*values*' has been setup properly depends upon your specific situation.

Answer (score 2):

The `GLKVector3MakeWithArray` function expects the argument to be of type `float[3]`. But you are trying to pass a single `float` value.

Create the proper argument from the elements of the array.